# Memsql procedure error for reading from Query JSON

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, singlestore

I am trying to read from Kafka topic which has to be populated into multiple tables in memsql.

Below procedure I am using which will be called in a pipeline:

```
DELIMITER //
USING my_db_demo
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_batch_json(batch query(my_json json)) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO demo_json_table(id)
SELECT my_json::id FROM batch;
INSERT INTO demo_json_table2(name)
SELECT my_json::name FROM batch;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

On execution of the proc I am getting the error:

> “ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ‘PROCEDURE test_batch_json(batch query(my_json
>   json)) AS BEGIN INSERT INTO d’ at line 1 ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table
>   ‘my_db_demo.batch’ doesn’t exist”

I am new to memsql and currently using Version: 6.7.5. Below is the format of the json I am using, how to resolve the error, not sure if batch here is a table:

{"id": 345, "name": "Roony"}

Thanks

Comment: `Table ‘my_db_demo.batch’ doesn’t exist`

Comment: This is part of Procedure pipeline mentioned here https://www.memsql.com/blog/6-5-pipelines/ . I am not sure if the batch is to part of a table which is my question.

Answer (score 0):

@giorgos-myrianthous nails it in the comments.  The answer is at the end of the error message: `Table ‘my_db_demo.batch’ doesn’t exist`  You're trying to create a stored procedure that will access a table which doesn't exist.  Create the `batch` table in the `my_db_demo` database and you should get further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see the error, but what I am highlighting is that the batch in the procedure is a parameter and this is not a table. I might be missing some metadata creation, this worked in memsql studio and not in my local memsql setup.

Comment: You are correct. I missed that it was a parameter into the sproc. It looks like the JSON query syntax may be what's biting us. Look at `json_extract_double(...` from https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/reference/sql-reference/json-functions/json_extract_type/ What's particularly weird is it worked in one but not the other. Are the MemSQL engines different versions between the two environments?

Comment: Yes version in my local is 6.7.5 and in studio it was above 7. However, the pipeline feature should work in my local version as well don't see this being a problem.